# Changing the values of a map nested in another map

Tags: groovy

Using HQL queries I've been able to generate the following map, where the keys represent the month number constant defined in java.util.Calendar, and every value is a map:

```
[
    0:[ client_a:[order1, order2, order3]],
    1:[ client_b:[order4], client_c:[order5, order6], client_d:[order7]],
    2:[ client_e:[order8, order9], client_f:[order10]]
]
```

order1, order2, ... are instances of a domain class called Order:

```
class Order {
    String description
    Date d
    int quantity
}
```

Now I've got that structure containing orders that belong to some specific year, but I don't really care about the Order object itself. I just want the sum of the quantities of all the orders of each month. So the structure should look something like this:

```
[
    0:[ client_a:[321]],
    1:[ client_b:[9808], client_c:[516], client_d:[20]],
    2:[ client_e:[22], client_f:[10065]]
]
```

I don't mind if the values are lists of one element or not lists at all. If this is possible, it would be fine anyway:

```
[
    0:[ client_a:321 ],
    1:[ client_b:9808, client_c:516, client_d:20 ],
    2:[ client_e:22, client_f:10065 ]
]
```

I know I have to apply something like `.sum{it.quantity}` to every list of orders to get the result I want, but I don't know how to iterate over them as they are nested within another map.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here You go:

```
class Order {
    String description
    Date d
    int quantity
}

def orders = [
    0:[ client_a:[new Order(quantity:1), new Order(quantity:2), new Order(quantity:3)]],
    1:[ client_b:[new Order(quantity:4)], client_c:[new Order(quantity:5), new Order(quantity:6)], client_d:[new Order(quantity:7)]],
    2:[ client_e:[new Order(quantity:8), new Order(quantity:9)], client_f:[new Order(quantity:10)]]
]

def count = orders.collectEntries { k, v ->
    def nv = v.collectEntries { nk, nv -> 
        [(nk): nv*.quantity.sum()]
    }
    [(k):(nv)]
}

assert count == [0:[client_a:6], 1:[client_b:4, client_c:11, client_d:7],2:[client_e:17, client_f:10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def map = [
    0:[ client_a:[[q: 23], [q: 28], [q: 27]]],
    1:[ client_b:[[q: 50]], client_c:[[q: 100], [q: 58]], client_d:[[q: 90]]],
    2:[ client_e:[[q: 48], [q: 60]], client_f:[[q: 72]]]
]

map.collectEntries { k, v ->
    [ k, v.collectEntries { key, val ->
        [ key, val*.q.sum() ]
    } ]
}
```

you can also use `val.sum { it.q }` instead of `val*.q.sum()`

Comment: Both answers worked well, but Opal answered first. Thank you anyway!

Comment: LOL. No worries. You get to know two different formats of using `collectEntries` one which takes a map (Opal's approach) another which takes a list (my approach). :) That is the reason I did not delete my answer when I saw Opal's approach is exactly same with a minute exception.